# Writing a script in Google Sheets to search a sheet for a string in a column and transfer information from that row to rows in another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I am trying to move information from one sheet into another based on the names of employees from a central database.

I'll try to explain the problem here with pictures and I will link the sheets at the bottom.

"Name Sheet 1" contains a list of employee names, along with what they had for breakfast today, lunch today, favorite food, favorite soda, favorite color, and favorite animal.

[Name Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdjNc.png)

[image]

The names were entered onto "Name Sheet 1" based on the date they joined the company. "Name Sheet 2" Contains the same information, however the names are now being entered based on their age, so the names are in a different order.

[Name sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZIzc.png)

[image]

Columns B and C are updated automatically everyday from another database, but columns A, D-G do not change. All sheet information in columns A-C are overwritten everyday, however they will always be in the same order, hence D-G do not update as they will not change unless a, employee is added/ removed which will be done manually.

Now that we are moving to "Name Sheet 2", I am trying to move all of the data from "Name Sheet 1" into this new sheet.

I am trying to write a script that will search "Name Sheet 2" for the name of an employee, copy the data for Columns D-G for that employee in "Name Sheet 1", and paste that information into the columns D-G for that employee in "Name Sheet 2"

For example; In "Name Sheet 1" we see that Bob is Row 2, but Row 4 in "Name sheet 2". This Script would Find Bob in "Name sheet 1", Copy D2:G2, then search Column A in "Name sheet 2" for "Bob", and when it finds "Bob" in A4, it would paste into D4.

I've been able to find scripts that can search a sheet and print the information into another sheet, however I haven't found any for searching that second sheet and copy/paste specific information.
Here is the code for this search functionality

```
var SPREADSHEET_NAME = "Name Sheet1";
var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 1;
var RETURN_COL_IDX = 0;

function searchStr(str) {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SPREADSHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
var row = values[i];
if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {
  return row[RETURN_COL_IDX];
    }
  }
}
```

Name sheet 2: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j6wt-ZDwnuXUf6Z3alyjUInuV2PHTdOweGf2L_JkxJ8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What script have you tried to write that didn't work?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, So far I've only made the script to search the first sheet/column  and get the information from the row, but haven't been able to find how to get search the second sheet and then paste.  `var SPREADSHEET_NAME = "Name Sheet1";
var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 1;
var RETURN_COL_IDX = 0;

function searchStr(str) {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SPREADSHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {
      return row[RETURN_COL_IDX];
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function copyDG() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Names Sheet 1');
  const rg1 = sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow() - 1);
  const vs1 = rg1.getDisplayValues();
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Names Sheet 2');
  const rg2 = sh2.getRange(2,1,sh2.getLastRow() - 1);
  const vs2 = rg2.getDisplayValues().flat();
  vs1.forEach((r,i) => {
    let idx = vs2.indexOf(r[0]);
    if(~idx) {
      sh1.getRange(i+2,4,1,4).copyTo(sh2.getRange(idx + 2,4));
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this with VLOOKUP statements in the cells, and not necessarily a script. The VLOOKUP formula would get the searchstring (the name) from column A of the current sheet, then go to sheet 1 and find that string, then get the value from the appropriate column.

For example, adding a VLOOKUP formula to cell D2 (Favorite Food, for Greg) -
The formula would reference the search string of Greg ($A2) , would search Sheet1 for that string (Sheet1!$A:$G), would return the value of that row in column D (4), and then set the "is_sorted" flag (usually set to false):

[image: Google Sheets Example Data cell D2]

The same formula could be used for columns E,F,G, swapping the 4 to a 5, 6, or 7 depending on which column to retrieve it from.

(You could of course also use the same formula for all columns B-G, not just D-G. )

Example of formula in cell G5:
[image: Google Sheets Example Data cell G5]

Comment: OP probably would have  included a Google-Formula tag if that was what  they were after.